# Why did The Looney Tunes Show change Lola's personality?

Tags: looney-tunes, space-jam, the-looney-tunes-show, lola-bunny

*The Looney Tunes Show* generally tried to keep all the characters personalities in sync with their classic persona. There is one exception though: Lola Bunny. In between *Space Jam* (her first appearance) and *The Looney Tunes Show*, Lola Bunny's personality did a 180.

In *Space Jam* (per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lola_Bunny)):

> Lola's personality is a combination of the Hawksian woman, tomboy and femme fatale archetypes. She is a tough talking, no-nonsense woman who is extremely independent and self-reliant. She is highly athletic and also incredibly seductive in her behavior, because she knows how beautiful she is and also because she knows how the male characters think of her.

But in *The Looney Tunes Show*:

> Lola also appears in The Looney Tunes Show, where she was voiced by Kristen Wiig. As opposed to her personality in Space Jam, she is portrayed as a scatterbrained, indecisive, gabby young rabbit who tends to obsess over Bugs, whom she refers to as "Bun-Bun." She is very dedicated to achieving goals but oftentimes tends to forget what she was doing. She's unable to settle on a decision, even for something as simple as what she wants to drink.

Have the creators of the show commented and or otherwise explained the decision to recast the character?

Comment: The Wikipedia cite note states why they included the character but not why they changed her _”"Lola Bunny appeared in Space Jam and will appear here too. Somehow she is a new character. We are glad that there is a girl, a female character as strong and funny as she was needed," said Cervone.”_

Comment: Does Lola have a classic persona?   Lola was invented for Space Jam, I would consider Classic to be 40s/50s era characters, Bugs, Daffy, Porky.  I'd say they are free to do what they want because it's not a deeply established character.

Comment: @rld  perhaps, but why did they change her? What wrong with the older one? And I want an official reason, not a guess.

Comment: @TheAsh to make her more funny/accessible to younger kids? Who knows

Comment: @RemyLebeau Hence my question. Maybe someone does

Comment: @Thomas fixed it

Comment: If you've ever watched Kristen Wiig play anything, then you'll realize that the portrayal of Lola is how she plays just about every character she plays.  So it may be that the character was re-written to suit the actor.

Comment: @PeterM That is an excellent observation. She does the same schtick in Despicable Me 3. Write that as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: @TheAsh Although it's compelling, it's only speculation on my part.  I'd rather see something definitive from someone connected with the show before I'd be happy putting that as an answer.

Comment: @TheAsh  And for all I know, she may have had a free hand in re-writing the part herself, although according to the IMDb she has no writing credits.

Answer (score 1):

Initially, she was created for marketing in the 90s. A lot of people remember her as an important character from the movie, but when you rewatch Space Jam, she has about 5 minutes of screen-time, and she doesn't really speak much past her initial introduction. Bill Murray had more screen-time than her, but she left an impression and her merch certainly did sell.

I would imagine they made the change because she was "too sexual" in the movie. The 90s was an entirely different era, and what worked in shows back then won't always work as times change. Look at the original antics of Bugs Bunny himself from the OG Looney Tunes (Merrie Melodies) shows, and you will see a very distinct difference between how Bugs himself behaved back then compared to how he is in TLTS. However, that alone might not justify or explain the entire change of Lola's character.

For instance: she could have gone from sexualized to a strong and silent type of woman with hidden sports skills and she still would have been appealing to the show's intended audience - perhaps even better for them. This is the direction that I personally would have taken; but then there would have been 2 no-nonsense female love interests for the main characters (Bugs and Daffy), and when writing any show, that tends to make things boring and could even be mistaken for a lack of creativity or trying too hard to kiss-up to a female audience. Diversity of character personality is important for writing entertainment, after all.

They could have made a new bunny character for this (Lola's) new quirky personality concept, and let Lola be a cameo only by Bugs perhaps mentioning an ex-girlfriend who became a basketball star, but the TLTS Team already had a female rabbit (Lola) on the sidelines, so instead, they retconned her entire persona. The industry will normally avoid wasting resources, especially when it involves a character who was popular and sold merchandise prior to the recycling of their concept.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Please note that the question is looking for an explanation from the creators of the show, not personal speculation.